# How to interpret an GS1-128 UCC/EAN-128 Motorola with EMDK 2.6 or DataWedge?

Tags: barcode, motorola-emdk, datawedge, gs1-ai-syntax, gs1-128

I'm trying to read a ean-128 with a Motorola MC3190 device.

Reading the sample string **(00)123456789012345675(15)010105**, both Emdk and Datawedge return this: **]C10012345678901234567515010105**.

I read FNC1 character ( "*]C1*" ), but the other parameters, in this case (15), how do I find it?  There is not a special character that identifies it!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to read a GS1-128.  The first AI in your barcode (00) is the SSCC (AI reference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS1-128#Full_list_of_Application_Identifiers)), which is a fixed length of 18 digits.  So you'll know that AI 15 will start right after that.

Regarding using DataWedge vs EMDK to read the barcode: DataWedge could not deal with the control characters in a GS1-128 when I tried it.  Granted, this was a year ago(using .NET CF 2.0, and the most recent version DataWedge available at the time), so things may have improved since then.

The EMDK should read GS1-128s correctly.  When you attempt to view a string representation (say, in a debugger), you may see something funky, because FNC1 is a non-printable control character.  But internally, all the bytes should be there.

Comment: In new versions of DataWedge 3.0 you can map control characters to keyboard raw codes (function Keymap). The only control character you need to look for is <gs> which is only mandatory when you are reading variable length fields which aren't at the end of the string.

Comment: Ah, excellent.  DataWedge might be the easiest way to go, then, unless you already need the EMDK for other reasons.